# Convert timestamp to DateTime in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way in **Excel** to convert the timestamp in the format

`{"_seconds":1570448585,"_nanoseconds":834000000}`

to readable format (Human-friendly)?

`1-Oct-2018 12:00 PM`

Comment: Do you know the exact value of the timestamp ? Can you confirm if this `{"_seconds":1570448585,"_nanoseconds":834000000}` is equal to `1-Oct-2018 12:00 PM` ?

Comment: No! this is just an example for the format I want 
1-Oct-2018 12:00 PM

Comment: If we don't have the value (or example conversion) of the timestamp.. mind sharing how can we verify that the excel proposed conversion is correct/wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The seconds look like a UNIX timestamp.
UNIX time started counting seconds 1970.
To convert it you need to start with the date 1970-01-01 and add the days as a float.

```
=DATE(1970,1,1) + A1/60/60/24
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea how to extract the second only from this formate I have?

Comment: This is the format I am getting in the raw data
{"_seconds":1570448585,"_nanoseconds":834000000}

Comment: Since nanoseconds is 10^-9 I assume it means: `0.834000000` but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - There is a feature called "Text to column"

[image]